# wolfram alpha api node.js

Tags: node.js, wolframalpha

I use this Node.js code:

```
var http = require('http');
var createClient = require('./createClient');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
    var wolfram = require('wolfram').createClient("My ID");
    var question = "how far nyc to chicago"
    wolfram.query(question, function(err, result) {
        var results = result[1].subpods[0].value ;
        console.log("Result: %j", results)
        res.write(results);
    })
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

I have an error on `res.write(results)`
If I comment the cause of the error `// res.write(results)`, the result is displayed twice:

```
Result: "1158 km (kilometers)"
Result: "1158 km (kilometers)"
```

I would like to store the `result[1].subpods[0].value` in a variable (results) so that I can display it on the html page (res.write) and also use it later.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to read your code because it's not indented, but it looks like you're calling res.end() before res.write(), because the Wolfram query is asynchronous. Try moving `res.end()` after `res.write()` inside the same callback function block.

Comment: How to retrieve the "results" variable for later use